# Resolve package loading issues for Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, anaconda

I have created a new virtual environment "pytorchplay" within Anaconda Navigator to play around with the Pytorch library using Python 3.8. To this environment I loaded Pytorch and Jupyter (and all dependent sources).  If I launch an Anaconda terminal prompt from that newly created environment within Navigator and type "conda list," Pytorch appears in the list. If I launch an iPython terminal prompt FROM THE SAME newly created environment and type "pip list," Pytorch does not appear.  If I initiate a jupyter notebook FROM THE SAME environment, and type "pip list," Pytorch also does not appear. In this last case, I do have a local kernel instantiated with the correct virtual environment. So, three versions of ostensibly the same instance, but with differing libraries/packages. How is this possible?  (Apologies if some of the language is imprecise, I'm learning...)

I have checked any number of similar posts and questions, but cannot seem to locate the correct fix.  Should it be helpful, I have checked the paths. These appear below.  I would appreciate any assistance that can be provided. Thanks!

From the Anaconda shell:

```
(pytorchplay) C:\Users\rk264116>echo %PATH%


C:\Users\rk264116\Miniconda3\envs\pytorchplay;
C:\Users\rk264116\Miniconda3\envs\pytorchplay\Library\mingw-w64\bin;
C:\Users\rk264116\Miniconda3\envs\pytorchplay\Library\usr\bin;
C:\Users\rk264116\Miniconda3\envs\pytorchplay\Library\bin;
C:\Users\rk264116\Miniconda3\envs\pytorchplay\Scripts;
C:\Users\rk264116\Miniconda3\envs\pytorchplay\bin;C:\Users\rk264116\Miniconda3\condabin;
C:\Users\rk264116\Miniconda3;C:\Users\rk264116\Miniconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;
C:\Users\rk264116\Miniconda3\Library\usr\bin;
C:\Users\rk264116\Miniconda3\Library\bin;
C:\Users\rk264116\Miniconda3\Scripts;
```

And from the iPython shell:

```
In [5]: sys.path
```

Out[5]:

```
['C:\\Users\\rk264116\\Miniconda3\\envs\\pytorchplay\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Users\\rk264116\\Miniconda3\\envs\\pytorchplay\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\rk264116\\Miniconda3\\envs\\pytorchplay\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\rk264116\\Miniconda3\\envs\\pytorchplay\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\rk264116\\Miniconda3\\envs\\pytorchplay',
 '',
 'C:\\Users\\rk264116\\Miniconda3\\envs\\pytorchplay\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\rk264116\\Miniconda3\\envs\\pytorchplay\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\rk264116\\Miniconda3\\envs\\pytorchplay\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\rk264116\\Miniconda3\\envs\\pytorchplay\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\rk264116\\Miniconda3\\envs\\pytorchplay\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\rk264116\\.ipython']
```

Comment: How have you installed `pytorch`? Thorugh `conda install` or `pip install`?

Comment: I installed pytorch via Anaconda Navigator.     I know I can do it "manually" in the iPython shell via pip install,, but I'm an educator and I'm looking into using the Navigator to make things easier for early undergraduate students.

Comment: That is good. Using the anaconda navigator is the equivalent of running `conda install` from a terminal or through iPython. Does `pip list` show you `torch`?

Comment: From the Anaconda prompt, if I use `pip list` then `torch` is there, but not `pytorch`. From the same prompt, if I use `conda list` then the opposite is true.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is simply that there is a name discrepancy between the conda package (and the libraries name) `PyTorch` and the name of the python module that you are importing `torch`.

The package that conda installs and therefore knows about is called `pytorch`, hence you see that from anaconda navigator or when running `conda list`.

`pip` on the other hand is oblivious of what `conda` does. Since it is only able to manage python modules, it sees the `torch` package present in your environment.

Comment: Thanks!  Much appreciated.

Comment: @DSnewbie Feel free to accept the answer if it solved the problem. If not, let me know and I am happy to elaborate further